# Why is the texture not fitting to mesh

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I have tried to unwrap a texture but it's not working! I marked seams and unwraped it but the texture doesn't fit the face. What's wrong with the mesh? Is there a simple and easy way to unwrap the face? Any suggestion? Please help!. Thanks! (PNG file attached)
[image]
[image]

Comment: your first screenshot shows that your UVs don't match the texture you want to have applied, so I'm confused what exactly your problem is

Comment: @UnholySheep my problem is i have attached the png file (face of spiderman) i want to wrap on the mesh of the face

Comment: Yes, because you need to adjust your UVs - the automatic tools are highly unlikely to achieve the exact result you want (though you could probably achieve better results, but there's plenty of tutorials about that)

Comment: You need to ask specific questions on how to solve a specific issue, what you need here is a tutorial, there are plenty of them available for free online, Blender Stack Exchange is not the right place to ask for one.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is edit the UV "points" laying on top of your image in the image editor while you're in edit mode in 3D view. The points are not matching up and you should probably try to do a "Smart UV unwrap" when you press U while hovering over the 3D view. That should give you an approximate UV to your image. i'm not very good at UV maps either but it's as @UnholySheep said, you just need to match your UV's to your image texture. If the smart unwrap doesn't work, just edit each UV vertex manually to match the texture, maybe even use proportional editing. Look up "UV unwrapping tutorial" or something similar if this explanation doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your first screenshot. The vertices are not matching the texture. Thats the problem. Match the vertices to the background image and the texture will fit! ;)